# Не получается создать CRUD (LARAVEL + SLEEPING OWL)

Tags: php, laravel

Пытаюсь создать простейший *CRUD* на *Laravel 5.4* + *Sleeping owl 4.19*. Делаю точно по [этой](http://laravel.su/articles/laravel-sleeping-owl-crud-for-dummers) статье.

После изменения `AdminSectionsServiceProvider`, *Laravel* выдает ошибку:

```
BindingResolutionException in Container.php line 819:
Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> $class ]] in 
class SleepingOwl\Admin\Repository\BaseRepository
```

Что это может быть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все решил, есть версия SleepingOwl, которая поддeрживает laravel 5.4 
https://github.com/LaravelRUS/SleepingOwlAdmin/tree/feature/5.4